# Response Text is Blank When Ajax method is Recall

Tags: jquery, ajax

First Time Ajax Call Gives Perfect Result on Load Event, but When I call it with Element's click event (Recall) it will gives response: Text blank, and Status Code : 200 OK.

```
var url = window.location.href;
var customerId = 1;
var OrderBy = 0;

if (url.indexOf('?' + paramCategoryId + '=') != -1) {
    var categoryId = parseInt(decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.match(/(\?|&)categoryId\=([^&]*)/)[2]));
    if (categoryId > 0) {

        GetProductsByCategory(customerId, categoryId, OrderBy); // onLoad Ajax Call

        $("ul.sorting li:not(:eq(0)) > a").on('click', function() { // On Element Click Event
            OrderBy = $(this).parent('li').attr('Id');
            console.log(OrderBy);
            GetProductsByCategory(customerId, categoryId, OrderBy);

        });

    }
}

function GetProductsByCategory(customerId, categoryId, OrderBy) {

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: url,
        data: '{"customerId":"' + customerId + '","categoryId":"' + categoryId + '","command":{"PageSize":"8","PageNumber":"1","OrderBy":"8"}}',
        cache: true,
        async: true,
        complete: function(data) {
            if (data == "undefined") {
                targetElement.html(content);
                return;
            }
            var resData = JSON.parse(data);
            var categoryResult = resData.CategoryResult;
            BindProductsByDisplayMode(CallType.Category, viewType, targetElement, categoryResult);
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
            targetElement.html(content);
        }
    });
}
```

Only Post request parameter `OrderBy` is changed on Second Time call. Default `OrderBy = 0 ;` But when I call Second Time it gives Response Blank and Error at

```
var resData = JSON.parse(data);  => 'undefined '
```

Comment: `if(typeof data == "undefined")`

Comment: @PHPWorm... When I change the `cache=false`, response text is coming blank and while `cache=true` nothing is coming from the ajax response. Actually I guess there is no call performing second time. I can't see Ajax call url on firebug console. First time data and call working perfectly! Any gusess?